# syncfusion pdf compression on linux change image colors

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, compression, syncfusion

I have this code (.net core 3.0 console app)

```
        PdfLoadedDocument ldoc = new PdfLoadedDocument("a.pdf", true);
        ldoc.CompressionOptions = new PdfCompressionOptions();
        ldoc.CompressionOptions.CompressImages = true;
        ldoc.CompressionOptions.ImageQuality = 70;
        ldoc.CompressionOptions.OptimizeFont = true;
        ldoc.CompressionOptions.RemoveMetadata = true;
        ldoc.CompressionOptions.OptimizePageContents = true;
        ldoc.FileStructure.IncrementalUpdate = false;
        ldoc.Compression = PdfCompressionLevel.Best;
        if (ldoc.Form != null)
        {
            for (int i = ldoc.Form.Fields.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ldoc.Form.Fields.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        foreach (PdfPageBase page in ldoc.Pages)
        {
            int count = page.Annotations.Count;
            for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                page.Annotations.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        ldoc.Save("b.pdf");
        ldoc.Close(true);
```

if I run this code on windows it works correctly, iif I run on linux (centos 7) it changes image colors (this is a part of the PDF page)

[image: output comparison]

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: At first glance looks like a bug. Contact Syncfusion and file an issue.

Comment: Did you try not to remove metadata as it is possible this operation to remove image colour profile also.